# googleapiclient/ apiclient youtube data api v3

Tags: python, google-api-client, youtube-data-api, apiclient

I already installed the prerequisite libraries for using googleapiclient for python(Youtube data api v3). But while retrieving some data, errors are coming. the code was just same as from youtube api website. Kindly let me know the possible solution
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/b/PycharmProjects/project/search_list_keyword.py", line 3, in 
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
File "/home/b/PycharmProjects/project/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 75, in 
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 31, in 
    import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
ImportError: No module named request

Comment: looks like you have used request module but not imported it

Comment: Please post your code (here, not a link to youtube) and fix the formatting. See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: The code is same as provided in the link [github/search.py](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/search.py)  Moreover, i already installed the googleapi library as well using the command  $ pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client  and I am using PyCharm IDE to run the same code. But, error still persists.